# subject-verb agreement kind of question

Tags: verb-agreement

I am wondering if the use of "are" in the last subordinate sentence is correct. It makes sense that 'are' refers to 'nodal cover depths' while I think the correct antecedent is the number defined as nodal cover depths.

> Finally, figures 12 and 13 show the characteristics of the optimal solution obtained for test examples I and II, respectively, using CABAC in which the number in parentheses **are** nodal cover depths.

Comment: "... using CABAC in which the number**s** in parentheses are nodal cover depths." At the core, it is saying "numbers... are... depths."

Comment: You can use the singulars "the number" and "(the) nodal cover depth" with singular "is". Otherwise, use plural "numbers".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sentence refers to two examples, I and II. The depth measurements in parentheses have numbers, not one number. The problem is not the word *are* but number, which should be plural.

Is there "**the number** defined as nodal cover depths" or are there numbers in the parenthese? If there may be different numbers shown, fix the sentence with "...in which the **numbers** in parentheses are nodal cover depths."